# JBoss Developer Studio is not deploying JBoss ESB project contents

Tags: eclipse, jboss, jboss5.x, jboss-esb

I'm currently starting out using JBoss Enterprise SOA platform 5.0 (JBoss ESB 4.7, JBoss AS 5.1), and I'm trying to deploy the "helloworld" quickstart sample that comes with the platform.

This project worked for me at one point, but recently I noticed that upon deployment, the contents of the project do not get deployed - only the directory structure.  In addition to this project, it appears to be happening to all my projects.

So, I end up with something that looks like this deployed to the app server:

```
deploy/helloworld.esb/org/jboss
deploy/helloworld.esb/org/jboss/soa
deploy/helloworld.esb/org/jboss/soa/esb
deploy/helloworld.esb/org/jboss/soa/esb/samples
deploy/helloworld.esb/org/jboss/soa/esb/samples/quickstart
deploy/helloworld.esb/org/jboss/soa/esb/samples/quickstart/helloworld
deploy/helloworld.esb/META-INF
```

Only directories, no files.

The server starts fine from within JBoss developer studio and the project builds and "deploys" without errors.  Nothing shows up in the server log when this happens.

I have added the project to the server using Add/Remove in the Servers view, as well as used Right Click > Run As > Run on Server, and in both instances it appears from a Developer Studio perspective to be deploying correctly (shows up as synchronized).

I've looked over project settings (libraries, and project facets mostly) and everything *seems* fine. I'm using the Java 1.6 and JBoss ESB 4.7 facets.

Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the "Deploy projects as compressed archives" box on the Deployment tab of the server configuration seems to work fine as a workaround, and the contents are included in the compressed archive.

Comment: i am new to jboss developer studio.actually using jboss application server i have implemented an application but which is totally based on command line,i.e i have not used any editor so far.but now i want to provide GUI for my application,for that i need to deploy my application on jboss developer studio.could you please tell me how you have deployed HelloWorld example on jboss developer studio.thanks in advance.it would be of great help to me.